# Migrating multiple Databases using Migration Assistant Tool - SQL SERVER to AZURE SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, migration, azure-sql-database, database-migration, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate all the old databases from SQL SERVER to AZURE SQL Database using Database Migration tool and successfully able to do.

There are more than 100 databases to migrate so for each and every database running the tool and repeating the process is lot of process.

Can someone help with migrating Multiple databases in one go or doing one at a time is the only solution.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only select a single database from your source to migrate to the Azure SQL database using the Data Migration Assistant tool.

[image]

You can create an Azure Database Migration Service resource in the Azure portal and select one or more databases to migrate from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database.

Refer this Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql#create-an-azure-database-migration-service-instance) for detailed process.